# Saving documents from Word to SharePoint Server new documents/changes not appearing immediately

Tags: sharepoint-server, document, word

We have an application that creates Word documents as part of its process; the users can then edit the document(s) and save them, then convert them to PDFs and e-mail them out to clients (this whole process is managed from the application). When the documents were stored as files on a file server, this worked flawlessly but now we are storing the documents in a SharePoint document library we are encountering a situation where documents are edited and then saved but the edits are not appearing in SharePoint for some time - usually measured in minutes.

We are using Office 365 (version 16.0.13127.21064) and SharePoint 2013 (I think - I'm not 100% sure how to check).

We tried changing the application process to move the point at which the document was copied to SharePoint to see if that made a difference. The old process was:

1. Copy template to SharePoint;
2. Insert (copy-replace) data in document;
3. Show document for editing;
4. User saves and closes document;
5. User hits "create PDF" button in application;
6. PDF created (using either Word or Aspose API) - **PDF lacks all data and user changes**.

The new process is:

1. Copy template to user's temporary files folder;
2. Insert (copy-replace) data in document;
3. Save document;
4. Copy document to SharePoint;
5. Open document for editing;
6. User saves and closes document;
7. User hits "create PDF" button in application;
8. PDF created (using either Word or Aspose API) - **PDF contains data but lacks all user changes**.

Experiments show that copying files to the SharePoint environment always immediately makes the latest version available - it's only saving from Word that seems to lag behind. We have disabled background saving both in Word and in the Word object created in the application to insert the data to the document; this seems to have made no difference.

Is there something I can change to get this process working?

Any help would be very gratefully received. Searching for the problem only turns up either unresolved issues like ours or other issues entirely, so I'm completely stumped right now.

Comment: What is triggering step 7 and where it is being triggered from?

Comment: HI @TrevorSeward - step 7 is the user, in the application, selecting the option to convert the document into a PDF and mail it out to the client. The application then uses the Aspose PDF converter to generate the PDF (we tried using Word but it doesn't seem possible to set a password on the generated PDF that way). The PDF is created directly from the document in the SharePoint document library, which doesn't contain the changes the user made and saved - they show up some minutes later.

Comment: Is it possible that the document which was saved has not been uploaded from the Microsoft Document Upload Center? This is a client that runs on the machine and using older versions of Office/SharePoint, performs the two-way communication from the client to server. While generally quick to save back changes, it isn't instant like it is with SPO.

Comment: Hi @TrevorSeward - I suspect it is something like that, but I can't find the Upload Center or disable it in any way to test that. One thing that I have found with additional testing since I posted the question is that saving from Word to another, older SharePoint server gives instant results every time, leading me to think it must be either a setting in SharePoint itself or that the Upload Center just doesn't work with the older version. I'll investigate the settings again today.

Comment: @Spratty Probably not so useful information here: Upload Center is automatically installed with Office, just search for “Upload Center” via the Start menu and it will come out. P.S. I have the same version of Office client installed in my SP13 environment.